# Convexity of $\frac{1}{f}$ over the set where the concave function $f$ is positive

Tags: convex-analysis

$S \subset R^n,~~f : S \rightarrow R $ is a concave function.
$S^{'}= \{ x \in S: f(x)>0 \}. $

> Prove that $\frac{1}{f}$ is a convex function on $S^{'}.$

Comment: It seems pretty standard with the definition of convexity and concavity, what have you tried? Can you show that $S'$ is actually a convex set?

Comment: @user37238   
$x_1, x_2 \in S^{'}$ implies $f(x_1)>0$ and $f(x_2)>0$

$f(\lambda x_1 + (1- \lambda) x_2) >= \lambda f(x_1) + (1- \lambda) f(x_2) >0$  for $\lambda \in [0,1] $

which implies, $S^{'}$ is convex

Comment: Good, so what's your problem with your question?

Comment: I could not proceed with the definition of convexity after then

Comment: May be you can use the convexity of the function $x\in (0,+\infty)\mapsto 1/x$.

Comment: In $S'$, $y>\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is equivalent to $f(x)<\frac{1}{y}$. Doesn't this imply that $1/f$ is convex?

Comment: @Siminore: if $y>\frac{1}{f(x)}$ and $f(x)>0$, then $f(x)>\frac{1}{y}$.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote $<$ instead of $>$. But it seems to me that the concavity of $f$ now implies the convexity of $1/f$ by considering epigraphs.

Answer (score 2):

Since concavity implies continuity, $S'$ is an open set and $\frac{1}{f}$ is a continuous function over $S'$, the convexity of $\frac{1}{f}$ follows from the midpoint-convexity, so we only have to prove
$$\frac{1}{f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)}\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}+\frac{1}{f(y)}\right)\tag{1}$$
for any $x,y\in S'$ such that $\frac{x+y}{2}\in S'$ (we can remove this assumption since $S'$ is a convex set by the concavity of $f$). We can write $(1)$ as:
$$ f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\geq HM(f(x),f(y)), \tag{2}$$
but the concavity of $f$ over $S'$ gives:
$$ f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\geq AM(f(x),f(y)),\tag{3} $$
so the claim follows by the AM-HM inequality - equivalent to the convexity of the $\frac{1}{x}$ function over $\mathbb{R}^+$.

---

Provided that $S'$ is a convex set, another approach is to consider that $\log f$ is concave on $S'$ since it is the composition of two concave functions, then $-\log f$ is convex, then $\frac{1}{f}=\exp(-\log f)$ is convex since it is the composition of two convex functions.

Comment: I think that the important point first is to show that $S'$ is convex. Plus, the fact that concavity implies continuity is much more complicated than the original statement...

Comment: The fact that concavity implies continuity was only used to reduce the problem to a simple midpoint-convexity proof, but you could re-insert the $\lambda$ parameter and follow the same lines, then use the *weigthed* AM-HM inequality. Just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that $f$ is already positive, since you know that $S'$ is a convex set. So, $\log \circ f$ is concave: indeed, for $1/p+1/q=1$,
$$
\log f\left( \frac{x}{p}+\frac{y}{q} \right) \geq \frac{\log f(x)}{p} + \frac{\log f(y)}{q}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\log f\left( \frac{x}{p}+\frac{y}{q} \right) \geq \log \left( f(x)^{\frac{1}{p}}f(y)^{\frac{1}{q}} \right),
$$
or equivalently
$$
f\left( \frac{x}{p}+\frac{y}{q} \right) \geq  f(x)^{\frac{1}{p}}f(y)^{\frac{1}{q}}.
$$
But 
$$
f(x)^{\frac{1}{p}}f(y)^{\frac{1}{q}} \leq \frac{f(x)}{p} + \frac{f(y)}{q}
$$
by some elementary inequality for positive numbers that you usually prove before Hölder's inequality. You conclude by the concavity of $f$.
Now, consider 
$$
\log \frac{1}{f} = -\log f,
$$
which is convex. Then $1/f = \exp \left( -\log f \right)$ is convex because the exponential is a convex increasing function.

Comment: The claim holds since the exponential is a convex function (the composition of two convex functions gives a convex function), not an increasing function: for istance, $\log x$ is increasing, but $\log(-\log f)$ is not always convex.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the answer.