# Notation: Show that the function $f^2/g$ is convex.

Tags: real-analysis, notation, convex-analysis

I am afraid I am confused about notation in the following question.

---

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is nonnegative and convex, and $g:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is positive and concave.

Show that the function $f^2/g$ is convex.

---

Does $f^2/g$ mean $f \circ f \circ g^{-1}$ or does it mean $f(x)^2/g(x)$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$?

The confusion is rather silly, but I am really not sure how to interpret this notation. I do not know what to prove if I cannot interpret correctly.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: $f \circ f$ doesn't even make sense here, because $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. So it's multiplication and division.

Comment: Oh my. I didn't notice that. Thank you!

Comment: Another giveaway: $g$ is assumed positive (i.e., constant strict sign) for a reason -- no division by zero.

Comment: [Convexity of the product of two functions in higher dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27571/convexity-of-the-product-of-two-functions-in-higher-dimensions) and [Convexity of $\frac{1}{f}$ over the set where the concave function $f$ is positive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653174/convexity-of-frac1f-over-the-set-where-the-concave-function-f-is-positi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty straightforward, though calculations are tedious. 
Basically you need to show that
$$
\frac{\left(f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)\right)^2}{g(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)}\leq
\alpha\frac{\left(f(x)\right)^2}{g(x)} + (1-\alpha) \frac{\left(f(y)\right)^2}{g(y)}
$$
for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and for all $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

From the convexity and non-negativity of $f$ and concavity and positivity of $g$ we conclude that:
$$
\frac{\left(f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)\right)^2}{g(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)} \leq
\frac{\left(\alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha)f(y)\right)^2}{\alpha g(x) + (1-\alpha)g(y)}.
$$
Then, it remains to prove the following inequality:
$$
\frac{\left(f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)\right)^2}{g(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)} \leq
\alpha\frac{\left(f(x)\right)^2}{g(x)} + (1-\alpha) \frac{\left(f(y)\right)^2}{g(y)}.
$$
However, after simple transformations most of the terms cancel out and you should obtain:
$$
0 \leq\left(f(x)g(y) -f(y)g(x)\right)^2,
$$
which is obviously true.